# editdtext with footer attached. footer disappears under softinputkeyboard when edittext gains focus

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have a footer in an activity. this footer contains. An edittext and a radiogroup postioned underneath the edittext. Almost like the footers footer. 
basically i use the radiogroup to select the keyboard type (emoji keyboard or regular keyboard). xml is below.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textbase_layout"
        android:background="@color/appwhite">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/window_background"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/comment_txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/comment_header_grey"
            android:hint="message goes here"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/appwhite"
        android:layout_below="@id/textbase_layout">
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_btn"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_radio"
                android:button="@drawable/keyboard_icon_selector"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/emoji_btn"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text_radio"
                android:button="@drawable/smiley_icon_selector"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="@color/bcg_blue"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have  WindowSoftInputMode= SoftInput.AdjustResize set also. When I select the edittext I want the whole footer to be pushed up. Including the radiogroup. but In some cases this isn't happening. The bottom radiogroup is being cut off by the softkeyboard. when I execute this line in my oncreate() method.

```
 Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden);
```

If i comment out the above line. the radiogroup is always shown, but it is creating a different unwanted condition in that the softkeyboard pops up when the activity is opened first?
Ive tried removing focus from the edittext also in this situtation, but the softkeyboard still pops up on entering the activity. If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this issue help would be appreciated.

Comment: When keyboard is displayed android will push only till control that is in focus. Your radio button are separate controls in layout and they wont be pushed on top of keyboard. You may want to use a toggle button on left of edit control just like most chat applications have for changing keyboard type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to change the your manifest xml ,,For which xml layout contains activity.

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"

OR

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

Change in MANIFEST FILE

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.adjustscroll.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know if solved.

Comment: not sure how to pass multiple params to windowsoftinputmode in xamarin ?

Comment: i think preventing the keyboard popup on entry without having to use Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden); would fix the issue